# Could the LHC create a strangelet by creating another multi-strange particle that then interacts with a nucleus?

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider, exotic-matter

I became interested in the discussions about potential catastrophic risk from colliders and I have some questions about it.

I am particularly interested in the strange matter scenario, and there is one thing I don't understand. I understand that the LSAG report (https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0806/0806.3414.pdf) shows that it is essentially impossible to create a strangelet in a particle accelerator. However, there are particles containing many strange quarks, such as the Ω-Ω dibaryon (which has six of them), which can theoretically be produced in collisions. If one of those particles were absorbed by an ordinary nucleus, such as one in a detector or the wall of the beampipe, what would happen to such a nucleus? (Note that the LHC does have detectors like VELO only a few millimeters from the collision point, so they could last long enough to get there even if they only lasted ~10^-10 sec) My understanding is that the nucleus would turn into a hypernucleus, but would it be possible for such a hypernucleus to decay to a strangelet with those quarks, if the strangelet with those quarks had lower energy than the hypernucleus? (This seems plausible because the hypernucleus will have more energy than the ordinary nucleus, so it might also have more energy than the strangelet even if that size strangelet is not yet absolutely stable. See for instance https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9809268.pdf, page 3 - “the MEMO would decay into a strangelet, if the latter were energetically favorable”)

If so, it seems like this would be a way to create a strangelet that isn’t ruled out by the LSAG report. It might also not be ruled out by cosmic ray collisions with Earth or the Moon, because these highly strange particles (if I understand it correctly) are easier to produce in the central rapidity region rather than the ends of the rapidity region.

What am I missing here? I admit that my knowledge of nuclear physics is limited so I might be just completely off base here.